# express.js multiple middleware issue, I can't seem to pass objects correctly?

Tags: express, jwt, middleware, access-token, refresh-token

```
profileRouter.get('/' , accessTokenValidator, refreshTokenValidator , async (req , res) => {

    try {
        
        const {customer} = req;
        const {accessToken} = req;
        console.log(customer); 

        return res.status(200).json({customer , accessToken:accessToken});
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});
```

here in this one, I basically want to return the user's info and a new access token to the client.

```
const accessTokenValidator = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not logged in' });
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, customer) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
    
            const statusCode = err.name === 'TokenExpiredError' ? 401 : 400;
            return res.status(statusCode).json({ err });
        }
        req.customer = customer; 
        next();
    });
}
```

In the first middleware, I check the validation of the access token. If everything is fine, I pass the payload as customer object on the req.

```
const refreshTokenValidator = async (req , res , next) => {

    const {customer} = req;
    const {id} = customer;
    console.log("id: ", id);

    const resp1 = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM refresh_tokens WHERE customer_id = $1' , [id])

    if (resp1.rows.length === 0 ){
        return res.send('refresh token not found');
    }

    const newAccessToken = jwt.sign({customer} , process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET , {expiresIn: "15m"});
    const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign({customer} , process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    

    await pool.query('DELETE FROM refresh_tokens where customer_id = $1' , [id]);
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO refresh_tokens (customer_id , refreshtoken) values ($1 , $2)' , [id , newRefreshToken]);

    req.accessToken = newAccessToken;

    next();
}

module.exports = refreshTokenValidator;
```

In the refresh token control middleware, I use the customer object's id field, to make a query to my database. I check if there is any refresh_token. If there is one, I make a new refresh token for my database, and a new access token for my client. Finally I send the renewed access token, for client to use.

***My problem is:***
This code works fine, if and only if I keep use the access token that has been created when the client first logged in. The refresh token in my database will be keep renewed, but whenever I decide to use a renewed access token, I get the error
***refresh token not found***

Why would that be happen? Why'd the first access token work, but rest of them wouldn't?

Thank you :)

Note:

I forgot to mention that ,the customer object on refreshTokenValidor will be a defined object with it's fields. Yet when I try to console.log the customer.id , it is seen undefined.

Using the first access token, it is never undefined. but trying another one, it will occure to be undefined.

```
const payload = {
            email: customer.rows[0].email,
            id: customer.rows[0].customer_id,
        }
        
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload , process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET , {expiresIn: "15m"});
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign(payload , process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

This is the main issue of the problem I guess.
How can an object be defined just fine, but when I try to log one of it's fields , it is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

In the refreshTokenValidator middleware,the customer object is not directly available on the req object. It is set in the previous middleware using req.customer = customer. you need to update your refreshTokenValidator middleware to access the customer object correctly.

```js
const { customer } = req //  Instead of using this
const customer = req.customer //you should use

req.customer = customer; // Add this line to pass the customer object to the next middleware
```

If this doesn't work, then you can try storing the required information in the access token itself.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However I've tried this approach, yet still didn't work out. No matter how I get the customer, there is the same result. First token can identify the fields of the customer, but the rest of them are still couldn't.

Comment: Have you considered storing the customer Id in the token itself And extracting it in the  middleware?

Comment: I think I'm already doing it. I'm signing the token with a payload which includes the customer id.  When I want verify it, the verify method of jws returns the exact same payload. I am usin this payload to create customer field on req , so it basically turns out req.customer = customer.

Comment: If you are meaning something else, I need you to enlight me on this one

Comment: Sure. I meant the accessTokenValidator middleware to include the customer directly in the access token payload, instead of attaching it to the req object. This way, the customer object will be available in the refreshTokenValidator middleware regardless of the access token used.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't honestly used you approach, but it definitely made me question the way I sign the new tokens. I wrapped the customer with curly braces , where customer is already an object. That's probably the reason why I had this issue. After making a new payload without iat and exp and signing it without curly braces fixed the issue. Thank you for your help and sorry for my foolishness :)